# MongoDB geonear and text commands driver 2.0

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm just wondering how I go about performing GeoNear and Full Text queries (not in the same query) in MongoDB using the new .NET 2.0 driver?

I can't seem to find any information on this relating to the new driver.

You used to be able to use the `Query.Text` and `myCollection.GeoNear` methods, but these don't seem to exist anymore.

Can anyone please point me in the direction of some documentation, examples or information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text queries, with `q` being the query string:

```
coll.FindAsync<Foo>(Builders<Foo>.Filter.Text(q));
```

Text queries *need* a text index. To create that from C#,

```
coll.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Foo>.IndexKeys.Text(p => p.Message));
```

Near queries:

```
coll.FindAsync<Foo>(Builders<Foo>.Filter.Near(p => p.Location, x, y, maxDis, minDis));
coll.FindAsync<Foo>(Builders<Foo>.Filter.Near(p => p.Location, 5, 5, 100, 0));
```

Again, these *need* an index:

```
coll.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Foo>.IndexKeys.Geo2D(p => p.Location));
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this has also shown me how to use the  $in functionality also :)